# Does $\zeta(s)^2 \pm \zeta(1-s)^2$ have roots at the $\rho$s?

Tags: number-theory, roots, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Maybe a strange (or stupid) question, but does

$$\zeta(s)^2 \pm \zeta(1-s)^2$$

also have roots equal to the non-trivial zeros ($\rho$) ?

At first sight you would expect so, however when I tried to 'root find' the zeros, I don't get any results at the $\rho$s for accuracies $>$ 14 digits. If this is indeed the case, could there exist any exponent (other than $1$) that does generate roots at the $\rho$s?

Comment: What algorithm are you using for rootfinding? If $s=\frac12+it$ is a zero of the zeta function, then $1-s=\frac12-it$ will also be a zero, and so your expression will have a zero there - but it may have some 'spurious' zeroes too.

Comment: Steven, I am using the RootFinding[Analytic]  function in Maple and I believe this is based on Newton's method.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily put a lot of faith in Newton-based methods to converge on the complex plane.  Do you get any convergence when you just ask it to find the zeroes of $\zeta(s)$?

Comment: Yes, all other root finding works fine up to very high accuracies and also for the exponent $1$ I find all the $\rho$s. However, when I plot the zeros for exponent $2$ at $1/2+s*i$ it can be clearly seen that the expected roots "at the $\rho$s" have a "parabolic dip", whilst the other zeros (that I all find at all accuracies) have a sharp downward "spike". You might be right that it is the shape of the curve at the zeros that confuses Newton's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the pair of functions $\zeta(s)^2 \pm \zeta(1-s)^2$ has zeroes at all the nontrivial zeroes of $\zeta(s)$. In general, 
$$\pi^{-s/2} \Gamma \left( \frac{s}{2} \right) \zeta(s) := \Lambda(s) = \Lambda(1-s)$$
and neither powers of $\pi$ nor the Gamma function have zeroes in the critical strip. So if $\zeta(\rho) = 0$, then $\zeta(1 - \rho) = 0$. This indicates that it is your root-finding algorithm that is encountering trouble.

Roughly speaking you should also expect very many extra zeroes to be present as well.

Comment: Thanks mixedmath. It must indeed be the root finding algorithm that struggles here. I found the same issue in Mathematica that also only at a precision of $<40$ digits could find the $\rho$. I did indeed find the many other zeros as well, but given some earlier questions I raised on MO (e.g. this one http://mathoverflow.net/questions/89518/are-the-semi-trivial-zeros-of-zetas-pm-zeta1-s-all-on-the-critical-li?s=6|2.0749), I believe these can all be proven to be on the critical line (which appears to be slightly more difficult to prove for the $\rho$s... :-)  ).